# Spring MongoRepository JPQL custom query

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm asking for help because cannot find any solution.

Here is an example of the custom query that I would like to build:

```
    @Query("{ $and: [ {$where: '(`?0` == null || this.courseLanguage == `?0`)'}, {$where: '(`?1` == null || this.category == `?1`)'}] }")
List<Course> findAllCoursesByNamedParams(
    @Param("courseLanguage") String courseLanguage,
    @Param("category") String category,
    @Param("level") Integer level,
    @Param("withCertificate") Boolean withCertificate,
    Pageable pageable);
```

The idea is that input params can be nullable, so.. I would like to build a query to db which will "filter" the data. With one parameter (courseLanguage) for instance - it works. In the current example, If I provide category value (not null) - it will work. But if I perform call with language value, but without category - no result. Any ideas what could be the problem here?

I tried another "format" of the query, but it doesn't work. Repo is defined like this:

```
@Repository 
public interface CourseRepository extends MongoRepository<Course, String>
```

Thanks in advance!